# DOJO Filtering select, drop it

Tags: dojo

I found how to change the displayed value in a filtering select, but now I would like it to drop the list, however i don't know how to do it?

Do you have any ideas?

Have a good day and thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by "drop the list."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var drop = dijit.byId('myFilteringSelect');
drop.focus();
drop._startSearch("");  // use whatever you want for the string to limit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have a reference book with all the method and what they are doing or maybe a website?

Have a good day.

Comment: I do not.  I just looked in the code for dijit.form.FilteringSelect to see what was called when the arrow was clicked.  I find myself doing that quite a bit with dojo.  
Also, would you mind 'accepting' this answer since it worked for you?  Thanks.